# Allow another close vote if original closure reason was trumped by others

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, vote-to-close

I voted to close a question as "too localized". At least three others incorrectly voted to close it as a duplicate. Once this error was spotted, the question was reopened.

I'm now unable to vote to close the question again because I voted the first time. However, my viewpoint wasn't heard because the majority voted for a different close reason.

Can we add a feature whereby you can vote a second time on re-opened questions if your original close reason was trumped by others?

Comment: Note: I suspect the answer to this will be "its not worth the effort". But I couldn't find another question on this site covering the same ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have any idea how specific this particular case is ?

You did indeed *used* your vote. It didn't end up the way you wanted it to I understand. But you still used it.

Like you said,

> "its not worth the effort"

And you're totally right. If you really judge this question is *too localized*, let the mods take care of it and help them by flagging it.

[image]

Comment: Your flagging suggestion is good. I tend to forget about that being a fall back option.

Comment: @DuncanJones I'm used to it since I can't cast close votes. If you run out of close votes AND flags, you're doomed.

Comment: Do users with 3K+ rep actually have the option "This question doesn't belong here..." for reopened questions they can't vote on? (A bit hard to find questions that fit that category for myself to test, but I don't have that option for any other questions.)

Comment: They do, @Wooble, but such a flag is automatically converted to a close vote and can't be raised if a vote can't be cast. PhaDaPhunk, flags for closure from users who have the VtC privilege must be "it needs moderator attention" -> "other" flags.